# SVG width does not update when resizing window

Tags: html, css, svg

I've found a weird issue where the rect inside the svg stays the same width as the svg on page load. Resizing the window (causing the svg to resize) doesn't update the width of the rect. Inspecting the element and toggling off/on the height or width then causes the width to update. This issue does not occur in Safari but does occur in Chrome and Firefox.

Is there a more correct way of doing the HTML and CSS to get the effect I need? I essentially want a dashed stroke around the box. I can't use dashed border as the dashes are not wide enough.

```css
.box {
  background: black;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 65px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}

svg {
  width: calc(100% - 46px);
  height: calc(100% - 46px);
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 23px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg rect {
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <rect x='1' y='1' rx='5' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image: Issue with width]

Comment: I've found this that essentially does what I want https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator/. But the issue with the svg not redrawing still stands if other have the same issue.

Comment: The width and the height of the rect are attributes.  Do not manipulate those in css. For what you need you may use divs instead. You don't need SVG

Comment: I needed svg to make longer dashes as per my description. I've found another way using a background image though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `border-radius` and `padding` properties to the svg and make the inner `<rect>` responsive using relative units.

```css
body {
}

*{
   box-sizing:border-box
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.box{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 23px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow:visible;
}

rect {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 8px;
  stroke-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <div class="box">
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
      <rect x='0' y='0' rx='5' width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Resize me</p>
```

`overflow:visible` will prevent any stroke clipping.
It is also important to set a `box-sizing: border-box` property - otherwise padding will introduce overflows.

This way we don't need any `calc()` width/height values, that can cause issues when applied to svg elements (... in some browsers).

Comment: Thanks, if svgs don't like calcs in some browsers then this seems like the way to go.